# Is "died by suicide" a correct use of preposition?

Tags: prepositions

Recently, when film actor Sushant Singh Rajput passed away, a famous daily reported it using this sentence: "While the police have confirmed that he has ***died by suicide*** ...".

Is "died by suicide" correct? If not, what would be the correct preposition?

Comment: Yes, that's the usual usage. You could say "from", but Google ngram shows "by" is about twice as common as "from".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thanks. When the cause of death is some disease, we use 'of''. In that context, can 'by' or 'from' be used? For example, "Someone died by/from cancer". Is it correct?

Comment: No, I don't think "died by cancer" is idiomatic. "From cancer"is common, though.

Comment: Another common expression is **died by his own hand**, meaning **committed suicide**.

Comment: I think "from" is used for a less immediate relationship - such as illness which causes failure of organs and death. But "died by suicide" or "died by gunshot".

Comment: In the UK the usual phrase would be to say that someone has "committed suicide".  I think the original sentence may be an example of Indian English. It sounds a bit weird to say "died by suicide", but it's not incorrect, just slightly odd from a UK English perspective. It would be understood.  Also [see this comparison in Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=died+by+suicide%2C+committed+suicide&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Because suicide implies death, "died by suicide" seems a bit redundant, and therefore maybe a little odd, although there's not necessarily a shorter idiomatic way of saying it. The verb "suicided" is possible but rarely used.

Answer (score 0):

A frequency comparison at Google ngram shows "by" is more common than the alternatives in "died by/from/of suicide"

[Google ngram "died by/from/of suicide"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=died%20by%20suicide%2C%20died%20from%20suicide%2C%20died%20of%20suicide&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdied%20by%20suicide%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdied%20from%20suicide%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdied%20of%20suicide%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdied%20by%20suicide%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdied%20from%20suicide%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdied%20of%20suicide%3B%2Cc0)